# List item extraction in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list

If I have `list = [1, [a,b]]`, how can I make split the list item in list to become `list = [1, a], [1,b]`?

Comment: is your list just like `[1, [a,b]]` or will it grow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first create a list then another.
then run nested for loops to individually print out each component of list2 + each component of list 1.
I spent a lot of time in this, so hope this has helped you out:

```
list1 = ["a", "b"]
list2 = [1, list1]

for i in list2[:-1]:
    for j in list1:
        print(str(i) + str(j))
```

If it helped, I would wish to get an 'accepted' mark!